# Why does my bash script not see my text files?

Tags: bash, git-bash

On my Windows 64 bit OS, I have a bash script that will read through a series of text files. I call it in Git Bash with the command 'sh script_name.sh' It is able to read the first, but for the others I am told 'no such file or directory'.

Does anyone know where I might be going wrong?

I found some advice suggesting checking the files in the directory with `ls -l` to see if `-rw-r--r-x`' is next to the files, then using the command `chmod +x file_name.txt` to correct that. I am finding that none of my text files have this, and using the command does not change anything.

```
#!/bin/bash  
cwd=$(pwd)  
echo $cwd  

while read x;  
do    
    cd C:\\FolderName\\FolderName\\FolderName\\FolderName  
    git clone "git@bitbucket.org:companyname/$x"  
    echo "git clone git@bitbucket.org:companyname/$x"  
done < file1.txt  


echo $cwd  

while read x;  
do  
    cd C:\\FolderName\\FolderName\\FolderName\\FolderName  
    git clone "git@bitbucket.org:companyname/$x"  
    echo "git clone git@bitbucket.org:companyname/$x"  
done < file2.txt
```

```
$ ls -l  
total 20  
-rw-r--r-- 1 username 1049089  597 Jan 23 13:55 README.txt  
-rwxr-xr-x 1 username 1049089 1270 Jan 28  2022 script1.sh*  
-rwxr-xr-x 1 username 1049089   23 Jan 23 13:52 script2.sh*  
-rwxr-xr-x 1 username 1049089 1932 Jan 24 10:35 script3.sh*  
-rw-r--r-- 1 username 1049089  577 Jan 28  2022 file1.txt  
-rw-r--r-- 1 username 1049089  318 Jan 22 14:51 file2.txt  
-rw-r--r-- 1 username 1049089   62 Jan 28  2022 file3.txt  
-rw-r--r-- 1 username 1049089  162 Jan 28  2022 file4.txt
```

It's worth noting that in the Bash script above, I've only included a sample of the code. I would have been running script 2, and included file 1 and 2.

UPDATE: I have written another script using the conditional `if [ -f ./filename.txt`  to check the files exist in Bash. They do exist.

Comment: Does the script `cd` to a different directory before opening the next file?

Comment: Also the output of `ls -l` would help (just the line that shows your specific file) :)

Comment: BTW: On the second `echo $cwd`, that variable is already outdated, since you did `cd ...` before. If you want to print the *current* working directory, just run `pwd` (= *print* working directory). No need for variables or `echo`.

Comment: Could it be that `file2.txt` has Windows line endings? That could explain why `file1.txt` works and `file2.txt` doesn't. Try to convert *all* your files to Linux line endings (e.g. using `dos2unix`). If that solved the problem, we can mark this question as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/39527571/6770384 for example.

Comment: I don't know the conventions in git bash to write down files, but I don't think that `C:\\FolderName\\FolderName\\FolderName\\FolderName` would work, as the the path separator is `/`  and not a backslash.

Comment: @user1934428 in git bash for Windows, Windows-style file paths are accepted, i.e. `C:\\FolderName\\FolderName\\FolderName\\FolderName` should work.

Comment: The files are in a directory (e.g. `/c/Users/elephante94` or `c\\Users\\elephante94`). Inside the first while loop the directory is changed to `C:\\FolderName\\FolderName\\FolderName\\FolderName`. The directory is not changed back to `c\\Users\\elephante94`. You may want to use `pushd` and `popd`.

Comment: Regarding "I've only included a sample of the code" - does the code in your question (and ONLY the code in your question) reproduce your problem or not?

Comment: Regarding "for the others I am told 'no such file or directory'." - don't just post part of an error message, post the full error message which probably includes the name of the tool that's failing and the line number where it fails. We've no idea if that error message is coming from `< file2` or `cd C:\\FolderName\\FolderName\\FolderName\\FolderName` or `git clone ...` or somewhere else.

Comment: Please, as the [tag:bash] tag you used instructs, copy/paste your code into http://shellcheck.net, fix the issues it tells you about, then let us know if you still have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you `cd` in a script that affects the working directory for the rest of the script.

Setting and examing `$cwd` in your script is a red herring. It's just a variable with no special meaning.

If you replaced `echo $cwd` with simply `pwd` (which **P**rints the current **W**orking **D**irectory, no `echo` needed) you'd see your working directory wasn't what you expect it to be.

The fix I'd go with is using `(...)` to limit the effect of `cd` on the rest of the script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while read x; do
    (
        cd C:\\FolderName\\FolderName\\FolderName\\FolderName
        git clone "git@bitbucket.org:companyname/$x"
    )
    echo "git clone git@bitbucket.org:companyname/$x"
done < file1.txt

while read x; do
    (
        cd C:\\FolderName\\FolderName\\FolderName\\FolderName
        git clone "git@bitbucket.org:companyname/$x"
    )
    echo "git clone git@bitbucket.org:companyname/$x"
done < file2.txt
```